# Is it possible to divide jenkins allure reports by environment?

Tags: jenkins, allure

i have a project in jenkins that runs automated scripts named "dp10_automation". Inside this project i have allure report.

Now i created two more projects "dp10_automation_dev" and "dp10_automation_uat" that runs every day and each one triggers "dp10_automation" in different environments, one runs in DEV and the other one in UAT.

I was wondering if there is any way that inside "dp10_automation_dev" and "dp10_automation_uat" i have allure reports with the data generated in "dp10_automation" from each environment.

So far i only have allure report in "dp10_automation" that have the data from all the runs in that project, DEV and UAT.

Is it possible to configure "dp10_automation_dev" and "dp10_automation_uat" so they get the allure results from "dp10_automation"?

This is how it's working today:
[image]

This is how i want it to work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to found a solution.

In dp10_auotmation i had to modify allure path in CLI to the other projects with this line: --alluredir=/data01/oracle/product/jenkins/workspace/${worksp}/allure-results

worksp is a variable that contains workspace name where the allure results should be saved.